# How to Make a Portable Jupyter Slideshow

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, reveal.js

How do I make a Jupyter slide show portable? I can serve the slideshow locally, but I can't send that to anyone and have it work with all the images, slide animation functionality, etc.

I am using `jupyter nbconver my_notebook.ipynb --to slides` and get a simple linear html file that depends on the files being on the machine where the file is used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should specify `--reveal-prefix` to convert it, [nbconvert doc](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#reveal-js-html-slideshow).

```
jupyter nbconvert my_notebook.ipynb --to slides --post serve --reveal-prefix "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reveal.js/3.3.0"
```

You may also use a local Reveal.js library, see [here](http://www.damian.oquanta.info/posts/using-a-local-revealjs-library-with-your-ipython-slides.html).

If you want a PDF, add `?print-pdf` to the address of the running html, like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_notebook.slides.html/reveal-js?print-pdf
```

Then save(print) it as pdf.

---

You may also want to have a look at [nbpresent](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nbpresent).

Comment: The first option `--reveal-prefix` is nearly exactly what I was looking for. Is there any way to freeze/embed pictures that are referenced in markdown cells though?

Comment: @aeolus I've no idea. I guess there are two workaround: save it as pdf or show your figures with notebook/ipython image tools like `IPython.display.Image`.

Comment: It's possible to embed pictures in HTML, as the figures generated by `matplotlib` are embedded. I guess you may find some tools to do this in HTML world.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715493/encoding-an-image-file-with-base64). I guess you may use python to convert your image to base64 string, and insert it to your markdown cell with `<img src="data:image/png;base64,...">`.