# Flask - how to read request.files['image'] as base64?

Tags: python, forms, flask, base64

I'm using Python Flask as my backend and faced a little problem.
In the frontend application I have a form that contains an image upload feature.

In the backend I refer a variable to the image with 
`image = request.files['image']`

That exports a `FileStorage` object.

I want to convert the image to base64 format in order to insert it to my DB. 
I tried a lot of things but nothing worked. 
Anyone knows?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Basically you need to read it as a stream and then convert it to base64 format.
Check the following answer:

[Encoding an image file with base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715493/encoding-an-image-file-with-base64)

The solution shoud look like this:

```
import base64

...

image = request.files['image']  
image_string = base64.b64encode(image.read())
```