# How to include a made screenshot to json/html report

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, screenshot, python-behave

I use `Bahave` and there is a next condition for `after_scenario` in `environment.py`

```
def after_scenario(context, scenario):
  if scenario.status == "failed":
    time_now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")  
    context.browser.save_screenshot("failed_scenarios_screenshots/%s_%s_failed.png" % (scenario.name, time_now))
```

How can I add a made screenshot into json or html report?

Comment: You could convert it to [base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715493/encoding-an-image-file-with-base64).

Comment: do you need the image inline in the HTML file (in base64) , or as a separate png file ?

Comment: yeap, I need the image inline in the HTML. And actually I will need it for cucumber report for Jenkins. So I need this attachment in json and then behave2cucumber converts json for appropriate cucumber report

Comment: @DenSilver - Did you find solution for the same? I am facing same issue.