# Base64 encode text files effectively and copy it

Tags: jmeter, base64, encode

I have large text files, which should be `Base64` encoded. I tried to open it in `Notepad++` and encode it with `Base64` converter plugin. It was finished in ~10 minutes, but I cannot select output string to use it in `JMeter`. Files are to long to select it and copy to some converters.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3715530/8293848 only three lines of python code. No need to open/copy/paste in editor.

Comment: @HayatiGonultas : How to paste in JMeter suite without copying it?

Comment: I hope jmeter  and other converters accepts input from file. In fact it seems that jmeter does accept file input.

Comment: No, it can't, check this: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61732

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following functions combination:

- [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) - comes with JMeter already
- [__base64Encode()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) - provided by [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project as a part of [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/) bundle

The syntax would be:

```
${__base64Encode(${__FileToString(/path/to/your/file,,)},)}
```

You can install `__base64Encode()` (and other) functions using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager):

[image: JMeter Plugins Custom Functions]

Comment: Request is executed, but I can't see details, because I get a white screen on response tab. I use these setting:
`set HEAP=-Xms512m -Xmx5112m` , but I see error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid9972.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [2861833605 bytes in 93.476 secs] Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. See log file for details.