# extracting zip file and storing it to image or file field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, zip

in my django project  i want a user to upload a epub file (basically a rar file) . i want to extract the epub file to get cover of that epub and save that to imagefield or a file field

my idea is to extract a file using zipfile module as a binary data, but how to convert binary data to image field or binary field

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def create_book(request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = Book_serialzier(
        data=request.data, context={"user": request.user})
    serializer.initial_data["title"] = serializer.initial_data.get(
        "book").name.split(".epub")[0]
    serializer.initial_data["user"] = request.user.id
    
    #here i started extracting
    with zipfile.ZipFile(serializer.initial_data.get("book"), 'r') as my_zip:
        if "cover.jpeg" in my_zip.namelist():
            serializer.initial_data["cover"] = my_zip.read("cover.jpeg")


    if(serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)):
        book = serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your problem statement, I understand that you want to extract the cover image from the epub file and then save that to your field.

`serializer.initial_data["cover"] = my_zip.read("cover.jpeg")`

This line reads the byte-string and saves it into your "cover" field. You can easily convert that byte-string to the image by writing into a file in binary mode.

```
with open('cover_image.jpg','wb') as imageFile:
    imageFile.write(fileData) #fileData is what you will read from "cover" field
```

---

*Best way to deal an image is to covert it in base64 format*

You can do that easily like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3715530/10627424)

To covert back that base64 string into image you can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2324133/10627424)