# How to send ImageFieldFile objects fetched from the database by django to the front-end and display them

Tags: django, vue.js

When using django as a backend, I have an image saved in the database in ImageField format, and in the view layer I get the object via orm, how can I return it to my vue frontend.

I turned the ImageField object into a string to return a JsonResponse, but the front-end only gets the name of the image when it's read

```
def getContent(request):
mtitle=request.GET.get('title')
row_obj=models.content.objects.filter(title=mtitle).first()
res={
     "pic":str(row_obj.img),
     }
print(type(row_obj.img))
return JsonResponse(res, json_dumps_params={"ensure_ascii": False})
```

How do I request the image to be displayed on the front end?

Comment: Have you tried turning it into a base64 image and return it to the frontend like that?

Answer (score 0):

The image field field will hold the image path.

You should use `<img src="image path">` in the frontend

Or convert image to base64.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3715530

You have to modify the image path yourself, this is just an example.

```py
with open(f'{static_path}/{row_obj.img}', "rb") as image_file:
    res = {
     "pic": base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
    }
```