# Retrieve and send a PostgreSQL bytea image

Tags: javascript, python, postgresql, bytea

I have an app which uses AWS Lambda functions to store images in a AWS PostgreSQL RDS as bytea file types.

The app is written in javascript and allows users to upload an image (typically small).

```
<input
  className={style.buttonInputImage}
  id="logo-file-upload"
  type="file"
  name="myLogo"
  accept="image/*"
  onChange={onLogoChange}
/>
```

The image is handled with the following function:

```
  function onLogoChange(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      let img = event.target.files[0];
      setFormData({
        name: "logo",
        value: URL.createObjectURL(img),
      });
    }
  }
```

Currently I am not concerned about what format the images are in, although if it makes storage and retrieval easier I could add restrictions.

I am using python to query my database and post and retrieve these files.

```
INSERT INTO images (logo, background_image, uuid) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}') ON CONFLICT (uuid) DO UPDATE SET logo='{0}', background_image='{1}';".format(data['logo'], data['background_image'], data['id']);
```

and when I want to retrieve the images:

```
"SELECT logo, background_image FROM clients AS c JOIN images AS i ON c.id = i.uuid WHERE c.id = '{0}';".format(id);
```

I try to return this data to the frontend:

```
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(response_list),
         'headers': {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"
         },
    }
```

I get the following error: `Object of type memoryview is not JSON serializable`.

So I have a two part question. First, the images are files being uploaded by a customer (typically they are logos or background images). Does it make sense to store these in my database as bytea files? Or is there a better way to store image uploads.

Second, how do I go about retrieving these files and converting them into a format usable by my front end.

I am still having issues with this. I added a print statement to try and see what exactly the images look like.

Running:

```
records = cursor.fetchall()
for item in records:
    print(item)
```

I can see the image data looks like `<memory at 0x7f762b8f7dc0>`

Here is the full backend function:

```
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    print(event['pathParameters'].get('id'))
    id = event['pathParameters'].get('id')
    postgres_insert_query = "SELECT name, phone, contact, line1, city, state, zip, monday_start, monday_end, tuesday_start, tuesday_end, wednesday_start, wednesday_end, thursday_start, thursday_end, friday_start, friday_end, saturday_start, saturday_end, sunday_start, sunday_end, logo, background_image FROM clients AS c JOIN address AS a ON c.id = a.uuid JOIN hours AS h ON c.id = h.uuid JOIN images AS i ON c.id = i.uuid WHERE c.id = '{0}';".format(id);
    query = postgres_insert_query;
    cursor.execute(query)
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    response_list= []
    for item in records:
        item_dict ={'name': item[0], 'phone': item[1], 'contact': item[2], 'address':{'line1': item[3], 'city': item[4], 'state': item[5], 'zip': item[6]}, 'hours':{'monday_start': item[7], 'monday_end': item[8], 'tuesday_start': item[9], 'tuesday_end': item[10], 'wednesday_start': item[11], 'wednesday_end': item[12], 'thursday_start': item[13], 'thursday_end': item[14], 'friday_start': item[15], 'friday_end': item[16], 'saturday_start': item[17], 'saturday_end': item[18], 'sunday_start': item[19], 'sunday_end': item[20]}, 'image': {'background_image': item[21], 'logo': item[22]}}
        response_list.append(item_dict)
    # print(response_list)    
    # connection.commit()      
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': response_list,
         'headers': {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"
         },
    }
```

Comment: What kind of data are you actually expecting with in each record? I mean from the memory object

Comment: I would expect a binary data type. Just not sure how to get that into an image on my front end.

Answer (score 1):

A byte format is not always castable to JSON, likely characters are used that are not allowed in json. Return a different data format. return a different datatype to your frontend.

For example, if you look at quill rich editor you'll see that you can send a base64 image in a .html file that you can send from backend to frontend.

I would also suggest that you use Sqlalchemy (https://www.sqlalchemy.org/), this makes your application SQL injection proof and also offers support for special datatypes.

## Workflow

### Load the image and encode with base64

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3715530/9611924

```
import base64

with open("yourfile.ext", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
```

### Send in your API request

```
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': {"image":encoded_string },
     'headers': {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"
     },
}
```

### Frontend

Decode the image .. (with base64)

Comment: Thanks for responding. So I would still be able to store the image in my Postico DB as a bytea format. When I retrieve the data my python server needs to convert the data to some other format before sending it to my frontend?

Comment: I think the problem is just the encoder that you used, and like mentioned, some characters aren't allowed in json. Look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1443240/9611924
Try encoding with base64, this should be allowed inside a json

Comment: Still struggling with this. I tried printing out the values returned from my database and the values for images look like `<memory at 0x7f762b8f7dc0>`.  Not sure if that is helpful.

Comment: I am not sure where the `with open` line belongs. Is that backend code? If so what is the "yourfile.ext".  I am going to update my post with the full python code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The `with open` line is one way to load an image, with "yourfile.ext" being the image path. But you already did this I assume because you have the `data['background_image']` variable. How did you create `data['background_image']`?

Comment: `data['background_image']` is part of the image upload. This is extracting the value of `background_image` from my network request to INSERT data into the db. I've updated my question to include the image handler function.

Comment: "The URL lifetime is tied to the document in the window on which it was created.", you don't create a byte file of your image. What you are creating is a reference to your image (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL#syntax). So I think you are saving a link that is no longer attached to the image. Replace that part with encoding of the image. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20285053/9611924

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the initial question.
But have you consider storing images on a dedicated S3 bucket instead?

That would be cleaner and not complicated at all to implement IMHO.
So you would store the actual image file on a S3 bucket and store its path in your DB.
Your database would be lighter and front will load image based on the returned path.

I know it could sound like a lot of changes but the AWS SDK is very well done and that is not that long to do.
This is what I personally use for my project and it works like a charm.

Comment: I thought about this but I am not really sure where to begin.

Comment: 1. Create a dedicated route that has the file as input, calls the AWS SDK to upload the file to the S3 bucket then returns the resulting file path.
2. Add a trigger to your file input that use your new route and display a loader and the uploaded file.
3. Send the file path from the front to the back into your form values.
4. Store the form values, including the file path, in your DB.
Then when you retrieve the form values, you get the file path and display it as any image URL.

Answer (score 0):

I tried https://www.backblaze.com/b2/cloud-storage.html.
Follow through doc, it's not that hard to upload a file. I mainly through command line, but the doc also offer other options.
After you upload, you can get all the uploaded file metadata.
So overall, you can upload file to backblaze(or other cloud storage) and insert all the metadata to database.
Then when you retrieve the images, you retrieve through download url.