# Can i keep any possible file formats in utf8 string?

Tags: encoding

I want to make a simple database where every recieved files will be stored in the same dump-file along with regular text data. I dont want to bother with storing them as uniq files in some folder on my server cos it looks very complicated. So can i convert any possible file formats (pictures, music, videos, archives etc.) into an utf8 string and just put it in a text file without any losses? Im sure i can open any file in notepad without exception but for some reason this operation is very slow and im not sure that notepad using exactly utf8 always so cant answer by myself.

I was trying to google it but seems like im the first crazy person with such an idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encoding an image file with base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715493/encoding-an-image-file-with-base64)

Comment: @JosefZ not at all. My question not about only images and not bound to any program language.