# Strange behaviour when converting base64 string to png in Python

Tags: python, base64, png

Hello I'm new to the concept of base64 images. I was trying to convert base64 "links" in a HTML to png files in Python, but the png generated seems to be damaged and I don't know why... Here is my code (in python 3.6)

```
encoded = (string2[0].split(",")[1]).encode("utf-8")
with open(r"myDirectory\example1.png", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(base64.decodebytes(encoded))
```

`string2[0]` is the full base64 string which I copied from the HTML. i.e. something like

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA0gAA...K5C%0AYII=
```

**The problem is essentially the following**: A png file will be generated, but when I open it, windows says "the file appears to be damaged, corrupted". However strangely when I open this base64 string in google chrome, the photo can be shown.

Anyone has encountered similar situation before?

p.s. I was thinking to provide the full base64 string, but it's very very long. Anyone knows how to paste such a long string to the question? e.g. a "dragable box of code" similar to what the OP has done in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395649/python-pil-create-and-save-image-from-data-uri?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Edit: The base64 string can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1--Y-YkgWdO2Nw69kuYCwT9REvGNGAtyH/view?usp=sharing). My first time sharing documents in google drive - let me know if you guys can access it.

Comment: While posting, you may edit the base64 string as `code` and you will get the "dragable box of code".

Comment: @user8212173 Thanks! But the string is so long that it has already exceeds the character limit on posting a question... So can't really do that. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Create a smaller image and post that one's base64 code. You can also try to upload one of the damaged PNGs on a public server and provide a link (I don't think you can attached a 'damaged' file to an SO post).

Comment: @usr2564301 Good idea thanks! I've just added a link to the google drive. Let me know if you can access it.