# How to Decode image URL extract from jsoup using Java

Tags: java, jsoup, decoding

currently i'm trying read some website content using **jsoup**. I got following result for Image Url.

```
<img alt="" src="**data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAP///wAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==**"/>
```

how do i get the real image Url of this image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image has been encoded. You cannot get the URL of the image , but rather you will be able to use base64 utils to get the image directly . This post will give you more information ([Decoding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106781/decoding-base64-images))

Online base64 converters can decode this string and you can save this decoded data as .gif and be able to open in a image editor / browser