# Receive image and save in database-django view

Tags: android, django, django-views, django-models

I'm working on an application where the client side is android and the server side is django. I usually send data to the server using post requests and recieve them at the server side in this way 
e.g. `name = request.POST['name']` 
I need now to receive the image in the server side and save it to the database. The image was converted at the client side(android) to base64 string so how can I convert that string to image at the server side and save it in the database?!

Any help?!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at a similar question, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323128/convert-string-in-base64-to-image-and-save-on-filesystem-in-python). If you do this, then you can just save the reference to the database for the image, or save the base64 string to the database.