# saving inline image from splinter

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, splinter

I have a page where an image is generated once some javascript is run. I can use `splinter` to get to the point where I have the image but I am unable to save it.

The code I am using is really simple:

```
    browser = Browser('firefox')
    browser.visit(png_url)
    browser.driver.save_screenshot(str(step+1) + '.png')
```

But the screenshot comes up empty...

The page is basically:

```
<body style="margin: 0px;">
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://localhost:8000/x">
</body>
```

I can right click and save the image but am not sure how to automate that with `splinter`.

Also, the image is an inline png, when I check the sources it reads as:

`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE` etc...

What can I do to automatically save this image? I am trying to generate a list of links and then iterate through them and save an image from each link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a delay allowing the image to appear via an [explicit wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(browser.driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "img")))

browser.driver.save_screenshot(str(step+1) + '.png')
```

or, with `time.sleep()` (not recommended):

```
import time 

time.sleep(5)

browser.driver.save_screenshot(str(step+1) + '.png')
```

---

Alternatively, [read that base64 image data, decode and save it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2324133/771848) (not tested):

```
image_data = browser.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("img").get_attribute("src")
image_data = image_data[22:]  # getting rid of data:image/png;base64,

fh = open(str(step+1) + '.png', "wb")
fh.write(image_data.decode('base64'))
fh.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! Your first example with the explicit wait was perfect, but I had to add `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By` to get it working.