# Error while saving base64 encoded image to the filesystem

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

I have tried to follow this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323128/convert-string-in-base64-to-image-and-save-on-filesystem-in-python) to save a base64 encoded image I receive in a HTTP request, to the filesystem:

```
imgData = re.sub('^data:image/.+;base64,', '', inner_data['output']['image'])

with open("imageToSave.png", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(base64.decodestring(imgData))
```

I have printed the string I'm trying to decode and it seems to be correct.

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/ [...] /+bax2njPQ8daytViRZP7UQbbmGRVEg6sPf1qYK0bCnKzuf/Z
```

But I keep getting this error

```
TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not str
```

Comment: Please always include the **full traceback**, not just the exception line. *What expression* throws that exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `base64.decodestring()` function expects *bytes*, not a `str` object. You'll need to encode your base64 string to bytes first. Since all characters in such a string are ASCII characters, just use that codec:

```
fh.write(base64.decodestring(imgData.encode('ascii')))
```

From the [`base64.decodestring()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.decodestring):

> Decode the `bytes`-like object *s*, which must contain one or more lines of base64 encoded data, and return the decoded `bytes`.