# How to get text from a base64 PNG image

Tags: encryption, base64, ocr, decode

This PNG image is in base64:

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

Is it possible to decode to get the text from it without using OCR technology?

The base64 code above will result in the following PNG image:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323128/convert-string-in-base64-to-image-and-save-on-filesystem-in-python

Answer (score 4):

Definitely not.

What you have is a base64 encoded PNG file. PNG files are binary files containing compressed pixel data, not text characters.

OCR would be the only way to try to recognize the characters in the pixel data.