# how to save canvas data as image using python?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, base64

I have been trying to save canvas data as image (png) using python and ajax jquery. But, getting blank image. Here is the codes below:
 JavaScript:

```
var dataimg=document.getElementById('canvas-data');
var dataURL=dataimg.toDataURL();
$("#save_to_server").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"save-canvas",
        data:{
            imageBase64:dataURL
            }
        }).done(function(o){
            console.log('saved');
        });
    });
```

Python:

```
@app.route('/save-canvas', methods=['POST'])
def save_canvas():
    image_b64=request.values[('imageBase64')]
    imgstr=re.search(r'data:image/png;base64,(.*)',image_b64).group(1)
    output=open('output.png', 'wb')
    decoded=base64.b64decode(imgstr)
    output.write(decoded)
    output.close()
```

Output:
[image]
followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323128/convert-string-in-base64-to-image-and-save-on-filesystem-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198131/how-to-save-a-html5-canvas-as-image-on-a-server) answers.
Can someone please tell what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: It is working on my machine.