# how to download image with scrapy when i got a base64

Tags: scrapy

I want donwload a image with this selector

```
image = response.xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/img/@src').extract()
```

with this, on the shell i have the result

> ['data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7']

Maybe is because the website is protected with hotlinking (cloudflare protection) and i need use other method? or simply im selecting bad the image for download

Comment: Already solved in another question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323128/convert-string-in-base64-to-image-and-save-on-filesystem-in-python

Answer (score 0):

After you get the base64 string:

```
# Assume you get this image list
image_list = ['data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7']

import base64

# Save image to file by using this code
for i, item in enumerate(image_list):
    with open("imageToSave{}.png".format(i), "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(base64.decodebytes(item.split(',')[-1]))
```

Comment: thanks but i cant assign only 1 name, because are like 400 diferents images, and with this code i got a error:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: May you can use a `for ... in ...` loop to traverse your images list,  like this:
```
# Assume you get this string
image_list = ['data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7']

import base64

# Save image to file by using this code
for i, item in enumerate(image_list):
    with open("imageToSave{}.png".format(i), "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(base64.decodebytes(item.split(',')[-1]))
```