# Trying to pass a base_64 encoded image to google authentication

Tags: python-3.x, base64, ocr, google-vision

So i am working on a small project(a restful service so json format which is not mentioned in the code) in which the code accepts base_64 image data and decodes it to from an image ,i'm able to convert it back to image but i am not able to use google vision(googel ocr) on the image to extract the text . The only part that isn't working is the following block of code:

```
from flask import Flask,request,jsonify
import os,io,re,glob,base64
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
from PIL import Image
app = Flask(__name__)
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']=r'date_scanner.json'
@app.route('/jason_example',methods=['POST'])
def jason_example():
    req_data=request.get_json()
    base_64_image_content=req_data['imgcnt']
#the issue starts from here 
    image = base64.b64decode(base_64_image_content)
    image=Image.open(io.BytesIO(image))
    image=vision.types.Image(content=content)
    response=client.text_detection(image=image)
    texts=response.text_annotations`
    enter code here
```

Comment: Please provide us with the exact error you are getting... And more information on what code actually needs to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use `Image.open` which I think is a `PIL` method anyway.    You should be able to decode this straight to a byte string with `base64.decodebytes`, as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2324133/2052575),

The code should look like:

```
# the issue starts from here 
image_bytes = base64.decodebytes(base_64_image_content)
image = vision.types.Image(content=image_bytes)
response=client.text_detection(image=image)
texts=response.text_annotations
```