# How to send text data with file from IoT device to Cloud IoT Core?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, mqtt, google-cloud-iot

I am sending images from a Raspberry Pi to Cloud IoT Core. This is working, but I now realised that I also need the filename of the file (or the data that I have added to the filename), when storing it in Google Cloud Storage, but as far as I can see it is only the content of the file that is sent. I have tried to accomplish this with the code extract below, but this doesn't seem to work, which I guess is understandable seeing that it is a byte array inside a JSON object..?

Is there a way at all? Is the filename somehow retrievable when sending via Cloud Function to Storage?

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    imagestring = f.read()
byteArray = bytes(imagestring)

now = datetime.datetime.now()
datetime_formatted = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")
filename = 'img_GM4_' + datetime_formatted +'.jpg'

payload = '{{ "ts": {}, filename: {}, "image": {}}}'.format(int(time.time()), filename, byteArray)

client.publish(_MQTT_TOPIC, payload, qos=1)
# Previously: client.publish(_MQTT_TOPIC, byteArray, qos=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to save the image in Cloud Storage you'll need to use a [Cloud Function with a Cloud Pub/Sub trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub#functions-deploy-command-python).

The Cloud Function should consist of the following steps:

1. Decode the data from the data property of the [PubSubMessage](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage) in a similar fashion to [this function](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/8215f45504c5358a72727e2a204302ea987561f8/functions/helloworld/main.py#L81).
2. Extract the value from the filename field and convert the [value string from the image field to an actual image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323128/convert-string-in-base64-to-image-and-save-on-filesystem-in-python).
3. Upload the image to Cloud Storage using one of the available methods. Like for example the [Google Cloud Client Libraries for Python](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/index.html) or the REST APIs and any of the available request libraries (e.g [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)). You can found coding examples [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) on the documentation.

Finally, notice that according to [best practices for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices#naming) you should avoid timestamp-based for your filenames (this will constrain your throughput). In the context of Cloud Storage it is recommended to create filenames in the [following manner](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-rate#naming-convention). So take this last message into consideration if you notice performance issues within your application.

Comment: This answer presupposes that the data is base64 encoded. I didn't do that since it wasn't necessary using MQTT. Do you mean it IS necessary to base64 encode, to be able to retrieve the file name?

Comment: Notice that in general the Pub/Sub message's data is stored as a base64-encoded string in the [data property](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage#FIELDS.data) of the PubsubMessage object. And that's why I included that step. If that is not the case you can omit the decode part and get the desired field.

Comment: How do I access the filename field? I didn't know there was one in the `event` object of the `helloPubSub` function. (I'm writing my functions in Typescript btw).

Comment: The filename field should be on the data (which you need to parse) of the Cloud Pub/Sub topic (which you should be sending with `client.publish(_MQTT_TOPIC, payload, qos=1)`). If you are not receiving the data on Cloud Pub/Sub please refer to [this](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/support/troubleshooting#im_not_receiving_telemetry_data_on_cloud_pubsub) for troubleshooting.

Comment: Ok. I get the data to Pub/Sub without problem, but I'd be really grateful for a description of how to (parse the data and) retrieve the filename.

Comment: Notice that the data you send is your `payload` variable and it is a string. Therefore you'll just need to deconstruct the way you initially created the `payload` variable. You could use a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to filter the value from the string or simply use the [string's split method](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), as for example the following command `print(payload.split()[4][:-1])` should print the required filename field from your `payload` variable.