# Python Requests: downloading data:image/jpeg;base64

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, base64

How to download with lib requests the following base64 encoded image:

```
url = data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

Pasting the above in a browser resolves into an image correctly

But `requests.get(url)` yields `InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))`

Attempting to first decode the above in https://www.base64decode.org/ also does not yield a valid url

Comment: What you have is the image data. There is no url here. You can write the base64 part of the string to file and you will able to see the result. Try in [base64 image decoder](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string in base64 to image and save on filesystem in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323128/convert-string-in-base64-to-image-and-save-on-filesystem-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323128/convert-string-in-base64-to-image-and-save-on-filesystem-in-python