# How to Decode base64 Image URIs

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, base64, uri

I'm connected to an API and one of the fields that it returns is this:

```
'image':'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=='
```

I know this is an base64 encoding of an image but I'm not sure how to decode it, I have already tested many online tools (just for checking the format it works) but none of them gave me the final image, how can I decode this with Python?

Comment: It seems like a very small string to be an image. Is it a tiny image?

Comment: It's literally 1 pixel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in Python3. The stuff before the string is just meta information that you need to skip over.

```
data='data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=='
img_data=data.split('base64,')[1].encode('utf8')
with open("imageToSave.gif", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(base64.decodebytes(img_data))
```

The image appears to be a 1 pixel GIF. Presumably a tracker...

Source: [Convert string in base64 to image and save on filesystem in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323128/convert-string-in-base64-to-image-and-save-on-filesystem-in-python)