# Convert base64 to JPEG in Python

Tags: python, base64, jpeg

I have the following program:

```
import fileinput
import base64

for index, line in enumerate(fileinput.input('input1.txt'), 1):
  if line.startswith('data:image/jpeg;base64,'):
    with open('image{0:04}.jpeg'.format(index), 'wb') as jpeg:
       line = line.strip()
       jpeg.write(base64.b64decode(line[22:] + '===='))
```

---

Intent is to pick base64 data from a file and create jpeg files from it. But somehow it is not identifying the starting characters as jpeg (have tried using jpg) and is skipping the data.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string in base64 to image and save on filesystem in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323128/convert-string-in-base64-to-image-and-save-on-filesystem-in-python)

Comment: on your screenshot I see it starts with /9j/, that`s a base64 encoded jpeg header. So you can directly base64 decode the file, there is no 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' data-url prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jps and @vishnudev. It works fine with the following changes.

```
for index, line in enumerate(fileinput.input('input1.txt'), 1):
    with open('image{0:02}.jpg'.format(index), 'wb') as jpg:
       line = line.strip()
       jpg.write(base64.b64decode(line))
```