# Form image data, how to handle image?

Tags: python, forms, image, flask, decode

So I send a `Form` to my Flask App and wish to receive the Form image data input and pass it to another function.

**Example of form:**

```html
    <form action="https://example.com/api/accept_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="fileupload"><input type="file" name="fileupload" value="fileupload" id="fileupload"  accept="image/*">
     Select a file to upload</label>
    <br><button id="submit">Post to Instagram</button>
    </form>
```

On the flask app:

```
def image_function(image):
     #DO SOMETHING WITH THE IMAGE

@main.route("/api/accept_form", methods=["POST"])
def manipulate_image():
    image = request.form["fileupload"]
    image_function(image)
```

I can see how the image data looks using the print command:

```
request.files["fileupload"] = <FileStorage: '666650673.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>
request.files["fileupload"].read() = b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00H\x00H\x00\x00\xff\xe1\x00 and so on ...'
```

How do I pass the image to another function in the Flask App as if it was the original `.jpg` submitted, called from the Flask Apps current directory using `"./666650673.jpg"`?

References:

https://linuxhint.com/python-string-decode-method/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2324133/14843373

https://github.com/williballenthin/python-evtx/issues/43

Comment: What do you mean by interact? That's a very broad term.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this file that has been uploaded? When a file is submitted to a server, the server takes that file and saves it as a temp file on the disk and then returns a file handle for it. So if you want to do something with the file then you use that file handle.

Comment: I was passing the image to another function that wouldn't accept the file handle or the bits string. Was hoping to pass it in without saving it but sure look.

Comment: you gotta give more details. No one can help you if all you say is "I'm passing it to a function that doesn't accept a file handle". Ok what function? Is this a function you created or to a third party? What is your end goal for this file? Are you just trying to save this file to the disk or send it somewhere else or what? But if you're happy with what you found that's awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, as @teddybearsuicide pointed out was that I was passing a file handle and not a file pointer.

Maybe there is a better way but I just saved it locally on the EC2 based on [this](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/werkzeug.FileStorage.html)

**Solution**

```
request.files["image"].save("./imageToSave.jpg")
```

And called it as you would any file in your directory.

```
image = "./imageToSave.jpg"
```

I would prefer not to have had to save it *so if anyone knows how to pass the file handle directly* to achieve the same effect that would be great.